# How do I sync a window's System-menu after SetWindowPos()?

Tags: c++, windows, resize, maximize

After `SetWindowPos( hwnd, HWND_NOTOPMOST, x, y, cx, cy, SWP_SHOWWINDOW)`, a window whose state was previously maximized, does resize and reposition itself as expected, but the system menu does not change, and still presents the menu items for a "currently-maximized" window, even though it is no longer maximized.

Following up with `PostMessage( hwnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_RESTORE, 0)` gets the system-menu looking right again, but it seems that I am mixing two themes here, and that posting `SC_RESTORE` is overkill, as this is already the window's state.

Is there a single command which resizes and repositions a window, and also sets the system menu to reflect a new max/min/res window state?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`::ShowWindow( SW_SHOWNORMAL );`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28VS.85%29.aspx) ?

Comment: Yes I have tried `::ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL)` but it resizes and repositions the window to its "original" startup size, and I want it to size to my specs.